# Getting an appsettings.json config value inside Program.cs with type safety

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

At the moment I'm using the code below in **Program.cs** to read a value from the appsettings.json file.What concerns me is that if I rename the section or the property (TimeOutInSeconds) to something else the code will compile fine but there will be a runtime error:

```
var timeoutInSeconds = configuration.GetSection("FluentApiSettings").GetValue<int>("TimeOutInSeconds");
```

Is there anyway I can access the settings in a strongly typed way by casting to a FluentApiSettings class?

Comment: See [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options). But binding would still be broken if property names don't match with section keys.

Comment: You're already using `GetValue<int>()`, why not go one level back and call `configuration.GetValue<FluentApiSettings>("FluentApiSettings")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ConfigurationBinder.Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_Bind_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_Object_) for this:

*FluentApiSettings.cs*:

```cs
public class FluentApiSettings
{
    public int TimeOutInSeconds { get; set; }
}
```

*Program.cs*:

```cs
var fluentApiSettings = new FluentApiSettings();
configuration.GetSection("FluentApiSettings").Bind(fluentApiSettings);
```

You can also make that a little simpler with [ConfigurationBinder.Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-configuration-configurationbinder-get-1(microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfiguration)), which creates the instance for you too:

*Program.cs*:

```cs
var fluentApiSettings = configuration.GetSection("FluentApiSettings")
    .Get<FluentApiSettings>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [IOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0) pattern in Asp.net Core to access configuration in a strongly typed manner.

*FluentApiSettings.cs*

```
public class FluentApiSettings
{
    public int TimeOutInSeconds { get; set; }
}
```

*appsettings.json*

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "FluentApiSettings": {
    "TimeOutInSeconds": 2 
  }
}
```

Now in *Program.cs* class

```
  builder.Services.Configure<FluentApiSettings> 
               (builder.Configuration.GetSection("FluentApiSettings"));
```

Use dependency injection to inject *IOptions* in your class like this.

```
 public class SomeService
 {
    private readonly int _timeoutInSeconds;

    public SomeService(IOptions<FluentApiSettings> fluentApiSettings)
    {
        _timeoutInSeconds = fluentApiSettings.Value.TimeOutInSeconds;
    }
 }
```